# Typescript Error "[ts] Expected 0-2 arguments, but got 3.", in Ionic 3 Framework

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

This is my http request I am making And I am using ionic-native/http plugin 
the error I am getting is 
**Error**

```
[ts] Expected 0-2 arguments, but got 3.
```

this is the Http call I am making

```
  getAcknowledgmentRequest(ssoId, alertType) {

    var url = this.globals.getUrl() + "receive_orderM";
    var body = JSON.stringify({ sso_id: ssoId, alert_type: alertType });    

    let bearer = 'Bearer ' + this.globals.getAccess();
    let headers = { 'Accept': 'application/json' , 'Authorization': bearer };

    return this.http.post(url,body,headers).then(
      (resp: HTTPResponse) => {
    return resp.data;
     })
  .catch((error: any) => {
      console.log(error);
  });
  }
```

this is method which is calling my service

```
this.messageService.getAcknowledgmentRequest(sso_id,alertType).then(
        (response: any) =>{   
            this.responseData =data;
            this.orders =this.responseData ;
            if (this.orders.length == 0) {
              this.showMessage = true;
            }
            loading.dismiss();         
        },
         catch(error => {
     Console.log(error);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct body for a `post` is an object, not a string:

```
var body = JSON.stringify({ sso_id: ssoId, alert_type: alertType });
```

Should be:

```
var body = { sso_id: ssoId, alert_type: alertType };
```

Comment: @NITISH do you have any errors / line numbers / other info about that?

Comment: I guess it's related to type of the  function